# Why isn't df.drop removing a column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to work out why df.drop() isn't working as expected. When I run df.drop with a column title that doesn't exist, it throws an error. This runs without causing any errors and I have copy pasted the title of the column so I'm sure it's the correct title.

Maybe I am misunderstanding how it works but I am expecting df.drop() to remove the column so that only the index and other 2 columns remain.

```
print(old_df.head(3))
print(old_df.keys())
old_df.drop('Unnamed: 0',axis=1)
print(old_df.head(3))



   Unnamed: 0           Timestamps                            Bodies
0           0  2020-04-21 01:19:09                           Body1
1           1  2020-04-21 01:19:30                           Body2
2           2  2020-04-21 01:21:35                           Body3
Index(['Unnamed: 0', 'Timestamps', 'Bodies'], dtype='object')
   Unnamed: 0           Timestamps                            Bodies
0           0  2020-04-21 01:19:09                           Body1
1           1  2020-04-21 01:19:30                           Body2
2           2  2020-04-21 01:21:35                           Body3
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this question and then immediately found the answer.

```
print(old_df.head(3))
print(old_df.keys())
new_df = old_df.drop('Unnamed: 0',axis=1) # The original dataframe remains, but a new df will have all the original columns but not the dropped ones.
print(new_df.head(3))
```

Comment: You can also update the original df by using ```df.drop('Col Name', inplace=True, axis=1)```